# ./configure fails to find libmysqlclient library, unable to link, on raspberry pi 3

Tags: mysql, linux, build, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries

Installing an sql database on raspberry pi 3 w/ raspbian (armv71 = 32-bit) using the following command:

```
./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

I get an error:

```
**********************************************
  ERROR: unable to find mysqlclient library (libmysqlclient.*)
  checked in the following places
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mysql
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mysql/lib
        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib/mysql
**********************************************
```

Raspbian repos doesn't have "libmysqlclient", but instead has the following:

```
sudo apt search libmysqlclient

Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

default-libmysqlclient-dev/stable,now 1.0.2 armhf [installed]
  MySQL database development files (metapackage)

libcrypt-mysql-perl/stable 0.04-6+b2 armhf
  Perl module to emulate the MySQL PASSWORD() function

libglpk40/stable 4.61-1 armhf
  linear programming kit with integer (MIP) support

libmariadbclient-dev-compat/stable,now 10.1.37-0+deb9u1 armhf [installed,automatic]
  MariaDB database development files (libmysqlclient compatibility)
```

the default-libmysqlclient-dev is not a linkable library.

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep libmysqlclient
[returns nothing]
```

But libmariadbclient is..

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep maria
        libmariadbclient.so.18 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmariadbclient.so.18
        libmariadbclient.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmariadbclient.so
```

So i tried the following commands:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmariadbclient.so.18" --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmariadbclient.so" --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

but still get the same error as above. Need help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring directly to the library didn't work and I also tried building the library from source and referencing it but no luck there either. So, I referred to the parent directory and it worked!

```
./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
```

Thank you all and best of luck!